# Is it better to have a field with 'Unkown' value or to not have the field at all?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using elasticsearch 2.4.4. I have records about fruits in my ES. Some records have the field **'color'** specified with a value and the same field doesn't exist in the remaining ones. I'm worried that when the size of ES data increases, will this affect my query performance. Should I repopulate my ES data so that the records which didn't have color field, now have it with "Unknown" value or should I not have it at all.

Example of a record with color field

```
{
        "_index": "test_data",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVqlmVt1DMREQvQmAIpk",
        "_source": {
           "fruitName":"Apple",
           "origin" : "New Zealand",
           " weight" : "50gms",
           "size" : "3 inches"
           "color" : "Red"

}
```

Example of a record without color field

```
{
        "_index": "test_data",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVqlmVt1DMREQvQmAIpn",
        "_source": {
           "fruitName":"Banana",
           "origin" : "Europe",
           " weight" : "500gms",
           "size" : "6 inches"

}
```

So my question is that does elasticsearch perform better when the field exists with a random value than when the field doesn't exist at all.

Comment: if you search on color property es will return documents that have color property as result

Comment: @eyildiz my question is that is it easier for es to have all documents with color property for faster retrieval or is it faster when some records don't have it.

Comment: I dont think so, es will search on indexed fields not on docs